# How do I get the subsequent line from searching a file?

Tags: python

I have a text file. I would like to search this file for a certain word, and return the immediately subsequent line.

In my test case, I have many color numeric values preceeded by the name of the color. I want to be able input the color name and get the numeric value out. This is my code:

```
def colorF(c):
    h = 0
    r = False
    try:
        f = open("Colors.txt")
        t = list(f.read().split())
        for line in t:
            h += 1
            if str(c) in line:
                u = line
                print(u)
                go = False
                start = '('
                end = ')'

                with open("Colors.txt") as infile:
                    for l in infile:
                        g = l.strip()
                        if start in g and str(c) in line: go = True
                        elif end in g:
                            go = False
                            continue
                        if go: return (g)
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Can I get some help? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide a sample file. Just a few lines, so we know the general structure.

Comment: Also your code freaks me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating your code. First, simplify by only reading the file once, one line at a time, and only returning the [next line](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_next.htm) if you find the color name in a given line:

```
def colorF(colorName):
    with open("Colors.txt") as colorFile:
        for line in colorFile:
            if str(colorName) in line:
                try:
                    return next(colorFile)
                except StopIteration:
                    raise Exception("File is malformed: no value existed after color found.")  # There is probably a more specific iteration that works here
        return Exception("Color not found")  # There is probably a more appropriate exception to return here
```

Your code has a bunch of other mishagus: it's unclear what you're trying to do with that, but based on your description it seems unnecessary.

The `Exception` raising will happen if the color isn't found or the file found the color but there was no subsequent value. This could be handled a number of ways, but it's advised you raise an exception in this case so that the calling code knows that it can't get a value from the file.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the format of the file since you're using a split is this:

```
Blue 12
Red 34
Green 56
```

And not like this:

```
Blue
12
Red
34
```

If that's the case I would use:

```
def colorF(c):
with open("Colors.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word in c:
                try:
                    ret = next(word)
                    return int(ret)
                except ColorError:
                    raise Exception("The specified color was not in the file.")
                    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what your condition is ... but this is probably the answer

```
for line in f:
    if some_condition(line):
        return next(f) # return the next line
```